# CakePHP bake command not working in CLI

Tags: xampp, cakephp-1.3

I have got an application that i am working on built using Cakephp 1.3 problem that i am having is that i am failing to bake using CLI. I am using Windows 7 and xampp as my localserver. This is how i have added my Environment Variables.

```
C:\xampp\php;C:\xampp\htdocs\myappname\cake\console\
```

When i type cake command in the CLI i get an error 'cake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this.

Comment: Read [console-for-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/10/03/console-for-cakephp/). You don't need the cake path in there (or better: you shouldnt have). Only php is needed. Just call your scripts with the relative path from your app folder: `..\lib\Cake\Console\cake ...` or `Console\cake ...`.

Comment: For 1.3 `..\cake\console\cake [command]` of course.